# How to identify electrostatic field function out of some given functions?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vector-fields, conservative-field

Suppose I have a vector function

$$\vec{v} = p(x,y,z) \ \hat{x} + q(x,y,z) \ \hat{y} + r(x,y,z) \ \hat{z}$$
How can I determine whether the given function represents an electrostatic field or not?

Comment: Welcome to SE. Dumping an exercise without showing any attempt to solve it isn't allowed here. Show what you tried, explain what you understand, and people will take it from there. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the curl of the vector functions ($\nabla \times \vec{v}$). The electrostatic field will have a zero curl.